# Pandas grouper date_time as per the market hours (Indian Stock Exchange)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Below data is in the interval of 5 mins

Dataframe names as df:

|  | script_id | date_time | open | high | low | close | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 201 | 2019-02-04 14:55:00 | 1408.05 | 1408.05 | 1407 | 1408 | 2384 |
| 1 | 201 | 2019-02-04 15:00:00 | 1408 | 1410.6 | 1407.2 | 1408.85 | 12621 |
| 2 | 201 | 2019-02-04 15:05:00 | 1408.85 | 1410.45 | 1407.05 | 1407.05 | 3880 |
| 3 | 201 | 2019-02-04 15:10:00 | 1407.05 | 1409.4 | 1404.85 | 1404.85 | 12992 |
| 4 | 201 | 2019-02-04 15:15:00 | 1404.85 | 1408.7 | 1403.5 | 1404.25 | 30803 |
| 5 | 201 | 2019-02-04 15:20:00 | 1404.25 | 1405 | 1402.7 | 1404.8 | 14624 |
| 6 | 201 | 2019-02-04 15:25:00 | 1404.8 | 1405 | 1402.05 | 1403.8 | 8407 |
| 7 | 201 | 2019-02-05 09:15:00 | 1400 | 1416.05 | 1400 | 1410.75 | 17473 |

trying to group it in 10 mins by executing below code:

```
df_f = df.groupby(['script_id', pd.Grouper(key='date_time', freq='10T', origin='start')])\
                        .agg(open=pd.NamedAgg(column='open', aggfunc='first'),
                            high=pd.NamedAgg(column='high', aggfunc='max'),
                            low=pd.NamedAgg(column='low', aggfunc='min'),
                            close=pd.NamedAgg(column='close', aggfunc='last'),
                            volume=pd.NamedAgg(column='volume', aggfunc='sum'))\
                            .reset_index()
            print(df_f)
```

Result:

[image: result]

**Expected Result:-** 0,1,2 are as expected below should be for 3 and there should not be 4.

|  | script_id | date_time | open | high | low | close | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 201 | 2019-02-04 15:25:00 | 1404.8 (value of 6) | 1416.05 (highest among 6 & 7) | 400 (lowest among 6 & 7) | 1410.75 (value of 7) | 25880 (sum of 6 & 7) |

How can we combine last two 5min tf to one 10min tf?

Note:- There are possibilities to have holiday gap as well between two days

[image]

Comment: This is not how I typically see interval financial data is analyzed. But to each their own! How do you expect the `15:25` and `09:15` rows to be combined? What time should represent their combination?

Comment: @CodeDifferent As here the data will be combined for 10 mins TF, whihc means we have to combine two as 1 and if `15:25` and `09:15` row will be combined then open will be of `15:25` and close of `09:15`. Also, like in second image the last data should be for `9:15` but took / assumed `9:10` in place and as a blank (all cols are of *09:15*)

Comment: it seems quite counterintuitive to combine 15:25 and 09:15 into one 10-min interval. It looks your intended grouping mechanism is different from what `pd.Grouper` is supposed to do. Maybe you could clarify the exact output you'd like to see.

Comment: @zyxue Have added the expected result, hope that have more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe:**

```
a = {'script_id': 'first', 'date_time': 'first', 'open': 'first', 'high':'max', 'low':'min', 'close':'last', 'volume':'sum'}

print(df.groupby(df.index // 2).agg(a))

   script_id            date_time     open     high      low    close  volume
0        201  2019-02-04 14:55:00  1408.05  1410.60  1407.00  1408.85   15005
1        201  2019-02-04 15:05:00  1408.85  1410.45  1404.85  1404.85   16872
2        201  2019-02-04 15:15:00  1404.85  1408.70  1402.70  1404.80   45427
3        201  2019-02-04 15:25:00  1404.80  1416.05  1400.00  1410.75   25880
```